# for loop is not working right

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, directx, for-loop

i have this loop that checks two objects.  The problem with it, is that it only checks the first one but it doesn't check the others...  When my loop check the first object for picking it says if it has been picked or not, but when it loops again to check the second object it says it has not been picked, even when it was picked.  So what i did is that i switched the checking process.  Like now the second object gets checked than the first object gets checked.  So after i did that, i got this result it says that second object got picked or not, it works fine but when it loops again it start checking the first object it says that it is not picked even when it was picked..
here is my loop

```
for(int i=0; 1>=i; i++)
    {
        matWorld=entity[i]->s;
        // Use inverse of matrix
        D3DXVec3Unproject(&rayPos,&rayPos,&vp,&matProj,&matView,matWorld);
        D3DXVec3Unproject(&rayDir,&rayDir,&vp,&matProj,&matView,matWorld);
        rayDir -= rayPos; // make a direction from the 2 positions
        D3DXVec3Normalize(&rayDir,&rayDir);

        if(FAILED(D3DXIntersect(entity[i]->pDrawMesh, &rayPos, &rayDir, &hasHit, NULL, NULL, NULL, &distanceToCollision, NULL, NULL)))
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        };

        if(hasHit!=0)
        {
            entity[i]->draw=false;
        }
    }
```

any idea?

**EDIT 2:**
ok i don't think you guys understood me right.  I'm not trying to make my loop check more `entity`.
Ok i'll this is what happening.
1.  When it loops for the first time it, checks to see if `entity[0]` is picked or not, This step works fine.
2.  When it loops for the second time,  checks to see if `entity[1]` is picked or not, HERE IS THE PROBLEM.
my loop works fine when it loops for the first time, but it doesn't work when it is looping for the second time.
When i was debugging i tried this.
1.  When it loops for the first time it, checks to see if `entity[1]` is picked or not, This step works fine.
2.  When it loops for the second time,  checks to see if `entity[2]` is picked or not, HERE IS THE PROBLEM.
it seems that after the first loop there is something wrong, but i can't see what is it.  By the way i don't get any errors.
**EDIT 3:**
The Entire Function

```
BOOL D3dDevice::Picking(HWND hWnd, LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev, CXFileEntity *entity[4])
{
    D3DXMATRIX matProj;
    POINT pt;
    D3DVIEWPORT9 vp;
    D3DXMATRIX *matWorld=NULL;
    D3DXMATRIX matView;

    GetCursorPos(&pt);
    ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
    d3ddev->GetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProj);
    d3ddev->GetViewport(&vp);
    d3ddev->GetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &matView);

    D3DXVECTOR3 rayPos((float)pt.x, (float)pt.y,0); // near-plane position
    D3DXVECTOR3 rayDir((float)pt.x, (float)pt.y,1); // far-plane position

    BOOL hasHit;
    float distanceToCollision;
    for(int i=0; i<=1; i++)
    {
        matWorld=entity[i]->s;
        // Use inverse of matrix
        D3DXVec3Unproject(&rayPos,&rayPos,&vp,&matProj,&matView,matWorld);
        D3DXVec3Unproject(&rayDir,&rayDir,&vp,&matProj,&matView,matWorld);
        rayDir -= rayPos; // make a direction from the 2 positions
        D3DXVec3Normalize(&rayDir,&rayDir);

        if(FAILED(D3DXIntersect(entity[i]->pDrawMesh, &rayPos, &rayDir, &hasHit, NULL, NULL, NULL, &distanceToCollision, NULL, NULL)))
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        };

        if(hasHit!=0)
        {
            entity[i]->draw=false;
        }
    }

    return hasHit;
}
```

Comment: That description is really hard to read with no punctuation.

Comment: Please use punctuation.  It's very difficult to understand your problem.

Comment: Try to rephrase, please.

Comment: Your i can only be 0 and 1. If you want more, you need to change the condition to include more.

Comment: Despite the punctuation, kudos to a 13-year-old working on game development in C++ (yes, he's 13!).

Comment: I'll post the entire function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have to reset the value of the rayPos and rayDir structures, because you change the initial values inside the loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<=1; i++)
{
    matWorld=entity[i]->s;
    // Use inverse of matrix
    D3DXVECTOR3 rayPos((float)pt.x, (float)pt.y,0); // near-plane position
    D3DXVECTOR3 rayDir((float)pt.x, (float)pt.y,1); // far-plane position  
    D3DXVec3Unproject(&rayPos,&rayPos,&vp,&matProj,&matView,matWorld);
    D3DXVec3Unproject(&rayDir,&rayDir,&vp,&matProj,&matView,matWorld);
    rayDir -= rayPos; // make a direction from the 2 positions
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&rayDir,&rayDir);

    if(FAILED(D3DXIntersect(entity[i]->pDrawMesh, &rayPos, &rayDir, &hasHit, NULL, NULL, NULL, &distanceToCollision, NULL, NULL)))
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    };

    if(hasHit!=0)
    {
        entity[i]->draw=false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should fix your `for` statement to:

```
int size = ... // detect the size of entity
for(int i=0; i <= size; i++)
```

now you write `1>=i`, it means `i` is less than or equals 1. So the loop works as you have coded it.

Answer (score 1):

If hasHit is the variable you are checking if the object has been picked, it doesn't look like you are currently checking a variable specific to each object. It appears just to be a variable that never gets updated in the for loop and will always hold the same value.

Comment: i don't think it is the problem because when i debug my code i can see when `hasHit` getting changed